# Save textarea form field when RoR validation fails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm trying to re-populate a form's fields when the validation fails, however the textarea field is not repopulating.

Here is my form (**new.html.erb**):

```
<%= form_for @testimonial, html: {multipart: true} do |f|  %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :company %>
  <%= f.text_field :company, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :comment %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 10, class: 'form-control'%>

  <%= f.label :avatar %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>

  <%= image_tag(@testimonial.avatar_url) if @testimonial.avatar? %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit "Create Testimonial", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the controller: (**testimonials_controller.rb**)

```
def new
    @testimonial = Testimonial.new
    session[:name] = params[:name]
    session[:title] = params[:title]
    session[:company] = params[:company]
    session[:comment] = params[:comment]
end

def create
    @testimonial = Testimonial.new(testimonial_params)
    if @testimonial.save
      flash[:success] = "Testimonial successfully added!"
      redirect_to testimonials_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Everything else is populating when the form validation fails, just not the textarea (comment).  You'll notice in the debug output at the bottom that the params[:comment] is being passed in the session.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

So, is there a different way to populate the textarea field to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your permitted fields in the controller: `testemonial_parmas`, check if the `comment` is included.